# CUDA MPI performance bottleneck

Tags: c, cuda, mpi

I want to clarify the following issue. I have access to a single node containing a Nvidia K40 GPU and Intel Xeon E5 processor.The processor details got using the lscpu command are as follows:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             4
NUMA node(s):          4
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2300.201
BogoMIPS:              4599.40
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15
NUMA node2 CPU(s):     16-23
NUMA node3 CPU(s):     24-31
```

I am running an MPI program which  distributes the work across the 32 cores of the processor. Each core then offloads some portion to the GPU. On running the code, the performance decreases (increase in execution time) rather than decrease? Is it because the the access to the GPU by the cores is getting serialized? I would just like clarity regarding this concept hence I have not posted any code. I have read about CUDA aware MPI ,but I think It is not much useful in this case as it is more applicable for multi node situations. Please correct me If I am wrong. What are the possible ways to improve performance in situations like these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because the the access to the GPU by the cores is getting serialized?

It's possible that serialization on the GPU may be contributing in some way to what you are observing, unless you are taking special steps.  MPI creates a number of *processes*.  A common strategy is to create one process per CPU core.  CUDA activity from separate processes (that targets a single GPU)  will normally be serialized on that GPU.

> What are the possible ways to improve performance in situations like these?

[CUDA MPS](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) was designed specifically for this situation.  It allows GPU activity emanating from separate processes to behave as if they were all coming from the same process. This can have several types of efficiency advantages (e.g. no context switching on the GPU, the possibility to run some GPU kernels concurrently, etc.), but I don't want to oversell the feature.  Whether and how much it helps in your case can only be determined by trying it.

If you are throwing lots of work at the GPU (per MPI rank) it's unreasonable of course to expect arbitrary linear scaling.  Once the GPU is saturated with work, things won't get any faster if the GPU is the bottleneck, and the additional overhead of additional MPI rank servicing may actually slow things down also.

[This presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2014/presentations/S4236-multi-gpu-programming-mpi.pdf), starting around slide 40, gives lots of useful information about MPS in this scenario.

Note that I'm focusing mainly on the GPU aspects here.  In general, MPI codes may not show linear scaling (and may even slow down, due to MPI overhead, and other factors) as you scale the MPI rank count from 1 to the total number of "processors" on your system.  There can be many reasons for this that have nothing to do with the GPU:

1. Process placement/affinity
2. Saturating the memory bandwidth of the CPU
3. Use of "hyperthreaded" cores in HPC codes often shows no benefit or negative effects.

And I'm sure there are many other possibilities as well.  So it's entirely possible that your performance slowdown actually has nothing to do with the GPU (if it turns out to be not the bottleneck) and is due to some other factor.  You can get some initial idea of this using profiling tools, and the above linked presentation offers some ideas there.